# How to enable client-side encryption in CAS

Tags: encryption, client-side, cas

Is there any internal configs in CAS for client-side encryption on login or a addon for this function

Tried searching in https://apereo.github.io/cas/
Found some configs to encrypt password in property files only but not the credentials on form submit

Comment: If I udnerstand your question right, you are trying to encrypt a password on form submission, which is technically on the broswer. If so, I dont think CAS has anything to do with the broswer side. Since, you are using CAS, I would assume that you would be already using HTTPS. In HTTPS, your request would be sent over SSL which is anyways encrypted.

Comment: Even a https request can be captured, if so the credentials will be exposed as clear text. Was wondering if CAS had any inbuilt configs for these

Comment: "Even a https request can be captured, if so the credentials will be exposed as clear text..." That is incorrect.